# Connecting Individual Modules - Chisel

Tags: chisel

Hello I have a question regarding how to connect and map the ports between two modules, I will describe only the inputs and ouputs while excluding the control logic for each. The first module is a simple register whose output is the input to second module which is a demultiplexer

```
class simpleRegister extends Module {
    val io = IO( new Bundle { 
    val enable = Input(UInt(1.W))
    val in    = Input(UInt(8.W))
    val out   = Output(UInt(8.W))
    })
}

class demultiplexer extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle { 
    val datain = Input(UInt(8.W))
    val dataout1 = Output(UInt(8.W))
    val dataout2 = Output(UInt(8.W)) 
  })
```

I am not sure if i should what method to use when I read " Interfaces & Bulk Connections" on github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to construct a top module that calls both the modules and perform the construction. This is pretty straight forward.

Your top module will look like this

```
class Top extends Module{
    //You can expose a top level IO bundle if you will
    val smplReg = Module(new simpleRegister)
    val dmux = Module(new demultiplexer)
    //connection of interest here is
    dmux.io.datain := smplReg.io.out
    //Make other connections as necessary
}
```

Interfaces and Bulk connections are when two IO bundles have similar fields instead of connecting each input/ output to the corresponding input/output you connect the bundle as a whole. This is just a way of optimizing your code.

Comment: it compiles now however if i try to obtain a verilog representation or try the internal tester i get this error 
~~~
 cmd17.sc:60: type mismatch;
 found   : Helper.this.TopMod
 required: chisel3.core.UserModule
~~~
it appears that I am passing the wrong type, as its expecting chisel3.core.UserModule

Comment: Can you show me a better representation of your error?

Comment: Also the error including `chisel3.core.UserModule` suggests you're using a pretty old version of Chisel (Maybe `3.1.something`?), I'd suggest upgrading to the newest, `3.4.2`.

Comment: I was using the juypter notebook, but now i will switch to scastie and it now throws this

"class Top needs to be abstract, since method io in class LegacyModule of type => chisel3.Record is not defined"

Comment: I've solved the issue that i was having, it was due to me not be explicit with the assignments of the io. I need to keep this in mind